# Nested IF() select in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

A normal `IF()` select in `mysql` would be as follows:

```
SELECT IF(1 > 2, 2, 3);
```

Question: how can I replace the last paramter with an additional `IF()` evaluation?

```
SELECT IF(1 > 2, 'bigger', IF(4 > 5, 'bigger', 'smaller'));
```

Comment: Your last example works just as it is, at least with MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your code should work, what makes you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you want to add another if a condition like below

```
SELECT IF(1 > 2, 'bigger', IF(4 > 5, 'bigger', IF(5>4,'true','false')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `case` expression!

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 1 > 2 THEN 'bigger'
             WHEN 4 > 5 THEN 'bigger'
             ELSE 'smaller'
        END);
```

`CASE` expressions are the *standard* way that SQL supports conditional logic.  `IF()` is a bespoke function specific to MySQL (and perhaps a handful of other databases).  I strongly recommend using standard constructs.